# optimization (faster) of postgresql FOR LOOP with 11Mio records to match against 25k rows

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a table from two other tables. My code works, but is really slow (20ms per gname record, so it would take 3+ days to complete).

Basically I have 11mio points and 25k grids and I want to generate a table where I link the grids with their respective points. I run through 1 gname record after the next, and check for each with ST_DWithin, if within its radius is the center point of any of the grids. If it is I want to save that info.

- gnames table has 11Mio records, each record can be in more than one grid (max4)
- grid table has 25k records

I wrote the following function using cycles (to set number of loops) and lpoffset (to start from specific point), because the DB crashed when letting it just run for a full day and nothing was written to the DB (seems it is written only once the loop completes?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gnames_to_grid(cycles integer, lpoffset integer)
  RETURNS integer AS

$BODY$
 DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    index integer:=lpoffset;

BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'start';

    FOR r IN 
       SELECT gnameid, the_gm FROM gname LIMIT cycles OFFSET lpoffset 
    LOOP

       EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO gname_grid 
       SELECT ' || r.gnameid || ', grid.id FROM grid
       WHERE ST_DWithin(' || quote_literal(r.the_gm::character varying)  || ',the_gm,100000,true) ';

       index = index +1;
       --count number of records written to table
       RAISE NOTICE 'after: %', quote_literal(index);
    END LOOP;
    -- return next offset
    RAISE NOTICE 'end';

    RETURN index;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I get a usage of 15% CPU and 30% RAM. I have set the values of the DB to use more, but no change in use or speed. Due to the lpoffset, I can actuall let the function run twice at the same time and then the CPU goes to 30%, but I beleive there must be a much better solution. I would be very happy if someone could teach me how to improve this.

Thanks

**EDIT:** to answer questions from "wildpassers"

Do you have indexes on the geo fields ?
gn has indexes (on coordinate column)
gr has indexes (on coordinate column)
(learned from https://github.com/colemanm/gazetteer/blob/master/docs/geonames_postgis_import.md)

Do they have bounding boxes ?
I though I did automatically by using the function - see first note under the below link
[ST_DWithin function](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

are there valid statistics ?
what do you mean here?

what is the query plan ?

for the LOOP - as it is called as a function, it does not seem to show all the detail (it was also run on 1000 rows), or is there some other way than just "explain"

```
"Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=26714.823..26714.823 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.017 ms"
"Execution time: 26714.836 ms"
```

for the JOIN

```
    "Insert on geoname_grid_2  (cost=0.00..1597498489.76 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=28343.040..28343.040 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1597498479.76 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=52.782..28319.443 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..150564231717.67 rows=94250 width=8) (actual time=52.781..28319.214 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (((gn.the_geom)::geography && st_expand((gr.the_geom)::geography, '100000'::double precision)) AND ((gr.the_geom)::geography && st_expand((gn.the_geom)::geography, '100000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin((gn.the_geom)::geo (...)"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15969526"
"              ->  Seq Scan on geoname gn  (cost=0.00..590016.50 rows=11064750 width=36) (actual time=0.004..0.545 rows=625 loops=1)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..816.31 rows=25554 width=36) (actual time=0.000..1.150 rows=25553 loops=625)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on grid gr  (cost=0.00..688.54 rows=25554 width=36) (actual time=0.233..5.001 rows=25554 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.202 ms"
"Trigger for constraint geoname_grid_2_geoname_geonameid_fkey: time=129.146 calls=1000"
"Trigger for constraint geoname_grid_2_grid_id_fkey: time=78.144 calls=1000"
"Execution time: 28551.360 ms"
```

The server-tuning ?
server is IntelCore I7, 12GB RAM, Winows 10 OS

for tuning (I didn't find a way to attach the whole file so here the main points)-let me know if something else would be useful:

```
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 9GB
work_mem = 100488kB
maintenance_work_mem = 1536MB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need a loop or dynamic sql here (none of the table names or column names is variable) You could rewrite to plain SQL. (the LIMIT and OFFSET may interfere, though)

Comment: I agree with wildplasser: you don't need a loop or dynamic SQL (or even a function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some further testing I recreated the whole table and run the code again. Now it went from 3h to 30mins. I now believe that for some reason, even when created the same way, that the index was broken in the first table.

Lesson for me: If something doesn't sound right, just delete, recreate, and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

[I don't have the table definitions, so the code below will be incomplete]:

```
INSERT INTO gname_grid (xxxx,yyyy)
SELECT gn.gnameid, gr.id 
FROM gname gn
JOIN grid gr ON ST_DWithin(gn.the_gm, gr.the_gm, 100000, true) 
    ;
```

Adding the limit and offset will need some extra work...

Comment: thanks. your proposal works, but the time is exactly the same, even a little slower. any other suggestions?

Comment: Slower is highly inprobable... Do you have indexes on the geo fields ? Do they have bounding boxes ? are there valid statistics ? what is the query plan ? The server-tuning ?

Comment: added answers above to the original text

Comment: Hmm, I am out of ideas. Strange thing that the geo indexes are not used. Can you find them back in the table definitions  ? ( `\d table_name` in psql )